How to use the CredentialProviderChain in AWS-SDK version 3
I cant find any concrete information about this process, i have the next code but i cant find how is this gonna be translated to version 3
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.CredentialProviderChain.defaultProviders = [
    function () { return new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS'); },
    function () { return new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AMAZON'); },
    function () { return new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials(); },
    function () { return new AWS.EC2MetadataCredentials(); }
];

let chain = new AWS.CredentialProviderChain();

 chain.resolve((error, credentials) => { etc...

